# Spring integration Error handling - How do I access original faulty message's history?

Tags: error-handling, spring-integration

We have a spring-integration application where we would like to deal with the messages on the error channel.At a minimum we would like to extract the history and log it so we can visualise where exactly it failed etc

Here is a brief markup of just this bit

```
<int:poller id="defaultPoller" default="true" fixed-delay="5000" />

    <int:channel id="MyCustomErrorChannel">
        <int:queue capacity="10"/>
    </int:channel>



    <int:header-enricher id="errorMsg.HeaderEnricher"
        input-channel="errorChannel"
        output-channel="MyCustomErrorChannel">
        <int:header name="history" expression="payload.failedMessage.headers" />
    </int:header-enricher>

    <int:service-activator input-channel="MyCustomErrorChannel" ref="errorLogger" method="logError"/>


    <bean id="errorLogger" class="com.dataprep.util.ErrorLogger" />
```

The idea is to define our custom error channel **MyCustomErrorChannel**.  Any error that ends up in the default errorChannel gets its header's enriched before being put out on **MyCustomErrorChannel**
Lastly we have a logger that reads the messages from **MyCustomErrorChannel** and logs the payload which is the underlying exception and also the history.

***I notice that the history in my logger is always 3 steps
errorChannel,errorMsg.HeaderEnricher,pbSwiftRouterErrorChannel*** i.e nothing prior to this message landing on the errorChannel is obtainable in the history.
How do I get hold of the original message's history (i.e the history of the faulty message which somehow landed on the default error channel as a new Error Message)

Could you please take a look at my header enricher and let me know how to access the headers on the failed message and stuff it to the error message?

Is it doable at all ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. To replace existing headers you should use `overwrite="true"`, because the `history` is built for the `ErrorChannel`, too.
2. You should override exactly with `history` header, not the whole `headers`. Therefore your expression must be like this:

   ```
   <int:header name="history"
               expression="payload.failedMessage.headers.history"
               overwrite="true"/>
   ```

Comment: He-he! Not like that. From the begging I was going to comment a bit different ;-)